# How to use Stripe payment gateway with java 1.8 and tomcat 7.0 without maven or any other framework

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am completely beginner in stripe.
I just want to add stripe payment gateway with java servlet  and jsp but I'm unable to find any tutorial for beginner.
Another important thing is that i want to run it on tomcat server localy from eclipse.
i have added stripe jar

another thing can we use stripe without spark because i have added spark jar in project library but it giving error.

Answer should contain imp points => select item from jsp page (by now) > what code should we write to handle that request in java (strictly no framework) > how to get response of success or fail with api .>if successful show alert else fail alert and redirect to item bying page .

remember: java 1.8, mysql 5.7, tomcat 7.0 , eclipse Kepler, run localy on localhost:8080

in answer :
a if any video tutorial

- jsp code
- java code(no framework)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using this [sample](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-payment/blob/35522cd579683355314105f822%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dnt-flow/server/java/src/main/java/com/stripe/sample/Server.java), which relies on a lot external dependencies and is using the Spark framework.

It's always easier to use a framework to build an API rather than reinventing the wheel. In your case, you might not need one, this is why you need to look at the docs (e.g. [accept a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements)) and use the server-side part in your jsp controller and the front-end part  in the webviews.

Comment: forget about framework and sample i want to create java server side and jsp client side  all code by myself so any suggestions ,tutorials for that will be grateful. everything new from zero

Answer (score 0):

Maven or gradle just gives option not to bother you with sub-dependencies. But you can do it at your own.

The problem looks like stripe has public api and implementation in separate libraries

The public part the API

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stripe/stripe-java
```

The runtime part implementation

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stripe/stripe-core
```

The sub-dependencies are on same page below. There is section

```
**Runtime Dependencies**
```

Follow the link and download jar files from section "Files" and add them to classpath directory.

Comment: thanks for the information I already added both jar .need help in development as i am developing from zero and not able to understand Stripe documentation